# Ajuda em Programação básica em python

Tags: python

Boa tarde, eu criei um programa que precisa ordenar os números e escreve-los em forma de string, o problema ocorre depois que eu ordeno, ele parece estar retornando uma lista vazia, pois quando tento executar o toString, quando eu debuggo eu percebo que ele sempre pega uma lista vazia...

O meu pensamento foi, vou percorrer os números existentes, achar o menor, jogar em uma nova lista e excluir o menor número da lista anterior e retornar a nova lista.

Aceito quaisquer dicas, pois sou iniciante.

```
class Ordenacao():

   def __init__(self, array_para_ordenar:[]):     
       self.__lista = array_para_ordenar      

   def ordena(self):
       array = self.__lista
       lista1 = []
       for j in range(len(array)):
           pos = 0
           for i in range(1, len(array)):
               if array[pos] > array[i]:
                   pos = i
           lista1.append(array[pos])
           array.remove(array[pos])
       return lista1
       
   def toString(self):
       array = self.__lista
       for i in range(len(array)):
           array[i] = str(array[i])
       str1 = ','.join(array)
       return (str1)
       
   
       
teste = [9, 0, 1]
orde = Ordenacao(teste)
orde.ordena()
orde.toString()
```

Comment: Acho que o problema é sua função `ordena` parece que ela retorna um array ordenada, ela remove os itens da array `self.__lista` no processo. acho que no final ela deveria substituir o `self.__lista` com a nova array ordenada.

Comment: @VictorAraújo Pequeno gafanhoto, eu não manjo de Python, mas dá pra ver que 1) se a ordenação e retorno da lista ordenada estiver correta, então na hora de chamar `orde.ordena()` você não está fazendo nada com o que essa chamada retorna, não está guardando em outra lista nem nada. 2) Talvez não precise retornar nada, poderia só apontar a `__lista` que guarda no objeto para a que você ordenou, dentro do conceito de atualizar campos de objetos (que pessoalmente não acho bom iniciante mexer no início do estudo de programação, pois POO é algo meio avançado, mas enfim, está na moda).

Comment: Onde no código tiver `array = self.__lista` substitua por `array = self.__lista[:]` e no final do código faça onde está `orde.ordena()`  faça `print(orde.ordena())`

Comment: Apesar dos títulos das perguntas sugeridas acima serem diferentes, o problema básico é o mesmo: vc está modificando a lista original, como já explicaram nos comentários (que também já deram o solução)

Comment: Solução não, só um reparo a solução vai além do escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Bom, pelo que o AP falou, o problema está sendo que ele está tentando imprimir uma lista que ele mesmo esvaziou, conforme a lógica que ele falou na pergunta que usou para ordenar. Faltou só jogar a lista ordenada por cima da lista esvaziada também (no caso não precisa copiar um a um os itens, só apontar a variável `__lista` para a lista que foi ordenada), aí o `toString()` vai ter mais chance de funcionar.

Comment: Quando você faz `array2 = array1`, tudo que você fizer na `array2` vai acontecer na `array1` também. Você tem que clonar se quiser criar uma cópia independente: `array2 = array1.copy()`

Comment: Aproveitando, no Python existe o método especial `__str__` que vc pode usar no lugar de `toString`. E entendo que vc talvez queira fazer a ordenação manualmente (talvez para treinar), mas em sistemas reais, prefira usar o que já tem pronto: https://ideone.com/GsRZ9L

Comment: @NatanFernandes A `lista1` para onde estão indo os itens ordenados pelo que entendo não aponta para a original, é outra lista, então o que eu falei deve funcionar, só fazer `__lista = lista1` ao fim da ordenação.

Comment: @hkotsubo, essa que apresentou é a solução.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Eu reli a pergunta várias vezes e meu entendimento é que o problema principal/específico é o fato da lista ficar vazia no final (e o motivo é endereçado nas dups indicadas). Todo o resto (`__str__`, o algoritmo de ordenação em si, etc), eu entendo que é secundário, então mantenho o fechamento (aliás, se alguém tiver outras sugestões de dup, pode comentar que eu acrescento). Mas claro, se alguém discordar do fechamento é só usar os meios usuais (votar para reabrir, abrir discussão no [meta], etc)

Comment: Bom, eu acredito que eu entendi onde eu errei, seria porque eu não devo excluir os elementos do array que está condicionado no meu método construtor, certo? o que eu fiz para solucionar foi meio que uma gambiarra no ´´´oderna()´´´ e coloquei ´´´self.__lista = lista1´´´ antes de retornar. Agradeço a todos pelas dicas

Comment: e @AugustoVasques, poderia me explicar, por favor o por que de precisar usar o [:] no array = self.__lista[:]

Comment: @hkotsubo, não discordo e nem quero reabrir a questão pois a pergunta é implicitamente ampla, pois inicialmente apresenta o problema mencionado mas trás consigo diversos erros de conceito que obrigatoriamente deveriam ser sanados e esmiuçados em uma solução. Por isso que não considero o meu código como uma solução mas sim como um reparo para que o autor já está fazendo enquanto o seu código sim elimina esses problemas que me incomodam.

Comment: @VictorAraújo esse código faz um clone superficial de `self.__lista`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques show!! não sabia dessa, a parte da Class já veio pronta, mas não entendia o porque tinha esses [:]  Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @VictorAraújo https://stackoverflow.com/q/6167238